# Analytic function in upper half plane.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function in the upper half-plane with $|f(z)| <1$. Now if $f( \iota  )=0$ then find the maximum possible value of $|f(2 \iota)|$.
Clearly Reflection principle is not working as real values at real is not given.
Then how do you find its maximum value? No idea is working. I think the function will be constant. Please suggest how to find this value?

Comment: Transform the domain to the unit circle and use Schwarz's Lemma.

Comment: how to transform ? can you help a little more.

Comment: There are bi linear transformations that transform the upper  to unit disc..

Comment: then how to use the given function?

Comment: please some one help me to solve this problem...

Comment: Consider the function $g(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$

Comment: yes it will transform upper half to unit disc...

Comment: i to zero ....now how to use function f

Comment: please describe exactly how to use f use find possible value of f...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation $T(z) = \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ sends the upper half-plane $H$ to the unit disc $D$. Hence $g := f \circ T^{-1} : D \to D $. Also, $g(0) = f(i) = 0$, so $g$ satisfies the conditions of Schwarz's lemma. Hence $\lvert g(w) \rvert \leqslant \lvert w \rvert $, for all $w \in D$. Since $T$ is a bijection, it is easy to see that $T(2i)=1/3$ and hence
$$ \lvert f(2i) \rvert = \lvert  f(T^{-1}(1/3)) \rvert = \lvert g(1/3) \rvert \leqslant 1/3. $$
(You can show equality occurs by setting $f$ up so that $g(w) = w$.)

Comment: nicely explained....thanking you....

Comment: @ chappers           thanking you....